# Как создать такую таблицу?

Tags: css

Подскажите, как создать такую таблицу, приведённую на рисунке?
В таблице разные по ширине колонки, и по разному прижат текст (влево, вправо, по центру).
Подскажите, как можно реализовать эту таблицу на flex?

Получается, что для каждой колонки отдельно нужно задавать ширину и выравнивание текста?  Или тут нужно разделить ряд не три колонки:

1. левая с изображением и названием
2. центральная с кнопкой и артикулом и кодом
3. правая с ценой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://jsfiddle.net/c4tjn93L/

```css
.form{
  .table{
   width: 100%;
  }
  .row{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   max-height: 119px;
  }
  .td{
   display: flex;
  }
  .item{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
  }
  .left{
   justify-content: flex-start;
   width: 33.21%;
   flex-basis: 33.21%;
   max-width: 373px;
  }
  .right{
   justify-content: flex-end;
   align-items: flex-start;
   width: 66.87%;
   flex-basis: 66.87%;
   max-width: 751px;
   .item{
    width: 25%;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    &:last-child{
     justify-content: flex-end;
    }
   }
  }
  .delete-product{
   width: 19px;
   height: 19px;
   color: #d24a43;
   top: 5px;
   right: 5px;
   line-height: 19px;
   font-size: 19px;
   background: #fff;
   opacity: 1;
   border-radius: 50%;
   box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   align-self: center;
   border: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   margin-right: 25px;
  }
  .img{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
   background: #fff;
   margin-right: 20px;
   img{
    max-width: 90%;
   }
  }
  a, span, p {
   font-size: 14px;
   color: #000;
   line-height: 18px;
  }
  .cart-title{
   text-decoration: none;
   &:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
   }
  }
  strong {
   font-size: 18px;
   color: #000;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 18px;
  }
  .price-old{
   text-decoration: line-through;
  }
  input{
   width: 44px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 18px;
   color:red;
   text-align: center;
   outline: none;
  }
  .r-btn{
   text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
<div class="table">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="left td">
       <button title="delete product" type="button" class="delete-product">×</button>
       <div class="img">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/product2.jpg" alt=""></a>
       </div>
       <a href="#" class="cart-title">Title</a>
      </div>
      <div class="right td">
       <div class="item articul">
        <p>Артикул: 03654</p>
       </div>
       <div class="item code">
        <p>Код: 32564</p>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
        <span class="minus">-</span>
        <input type="text">
        <span class="plus">+</span>
       </div>
       <div class="item price">
        <span class="price-old">2000 грн</span>
        <strong class="price-current">1000 грн</strong>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

так будет правильно?

Comment: Мне кажется, что такие таблицы легче сделать с помощью jQuery

Comment: @Nikita, скорее всего это делается легко и на css. Разве на jquery проще выравнивать колонки? по моему выравнивать проще на css

Comment: @word Вы в css в принципе что-нибудь понимаете? Это же элементарно делается...

Comment: @Andrey Fedorov, понимаю, но хотелось бы увидеть на более правильное решение

Comment: <hr> потом задать ему стиль, задать стил шрифта, задать стил <div> и все

Comment: @Andrey Fedorov, добавил свой вариант, подскажите, как его можно улучшить

Comment: Может рискнуть и сделать таблицу таблицей?

Comment: @word подсказываю. У вас в макете по сути только одно резиновое поле должно быть - наименование товара. Остальное все фиксированное. Не надо везде проценты лепить.

Comment: @Andrey Fedorov, а пример можете показать?

Comment: @word могу, но не буду, т.к. не вижу в вопросе проблемы. ваш код показывает приемлемое знание css, вы сами все можете.

Comment: @Andrey Fedorov, не затруднит ли вас показать, как правильно сделать такую таблицу? flex я только недавно освоил, ещё таблицы не делал на flex. С моим вариантом, показанным выше, трудно сделать соответствие макету

Comment: не получается почему-то сдвинуть колонки на нужное количество пикселей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уговорили. Примерно так. Как под себя переделать разберетесь сами.

```css
div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.wrapper div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.number,
.count,
.cost {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cost {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.title {
  flex: 1 0;
}


/* для фиксированной высоты линии */

.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.number,
.count,
.cost {
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="number">1</div>
  <div class="title">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="count">5</div>
  <div class="cost">1000</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="number">2</div>
  <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel vehicula nibh, vitae consectetur felis. Praesent id consectetur arcu, eget laoreet enim. Pellentesque vel lobortis tellus, et elementum justo.  </div>
  <div class="count">523874682</div>
  <div class="cost">2394792873498273</div>
</div>
```

Comment: теперь понятней стало, благодарю